# Split stdout and pipe each piece to command

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, unix, pipe

I have a `javascript` file that looks like this.

```
var val = "foo"
console.log(val)
//EVALMD-STDOUT-FILE-DELIMETER
if (!val) var val = "bar"
console.log(val)
//EVALMD-STDOUT-FILE-DELIMETER
console.log(val)
```

I can run it two ways.

```
node example.js
```

Or I can pipe it in with `cat`.

```
cat example.js | node
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can split a stdout like `cat example.js` by a delimiter in my case `//EVALMD-STDOUT-FILE-DELIMETER`, and pipe each with `node` as a separate process, so instead of logging `foo`, `foo`,`foo` I should get `foo`, `bar`, then an error.

The file above should get split and interpreted into 3 'chunks'

one:

```
var val = "foo"
console.log(val)
```

two:

```
if (!val) var val = "bar"
console.log(val)
```

three:

```
console.log(val)
```

Comment: In that example the definition of `val` will only happen in the first instance of `node`.  Am I interpreting that right?

Comment: Also, do you know in advance how many delimeters you'll have, or do you want it to find it dynamically and start a new instance of node each time it finds one?

Comment: @EricRenouf When node runs the js above `val` is declared one time, yes.

Comment: @EricRenouf I don't know how many delimiters will be in the string.

Comment: My `val` question was more along the lines that you'd have 3 "files" when split with those delims, and only one of them would include the line `var val = "foo"`, the other two would not have that line in them, right?

Comment: @EricRenouf yes I added update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial solution that can be extended if you know the number of splits in advance would be something like:

```
cat example.js | tee >(sed -n '1,_//EVALMD-STDOUT-FILE-DELIMETER_p' | node) >(sed -n '_//EVALMD-STDOUT-FILE-DELIMETER_,$p' | node) >/dev/null
```

with the last `>/dev/null` to keep `tee` from printing it to stdout as well

You could use `perl` to do it if you don't know things in advance with a script like:

```
open(my $out, "| node");
while(<>) {
    if(/\/\/EVALMD-STDOUT-FILE-DELIMETER/) {
        close($out);
        open($out, "| node");
        next;
    }
    print $out $_;
}
```

So you could cat a file into that, which you could either have as a perl script or you could collapse into a string and run it like

```
cat example.js | perl -nle 'open(my $out, "| node");while(<>) {if(/\/\/EVALMD-STDOUT-FILE-DELIMETER/) {close($out);open($out, "| node");next;}print $out $_;}'
```

or of course you could trivially modify the perl to read the file itself and so not to need the `cat`