# Bash split stdin by null and pipe to pipeline

Tags: bash, stream, pipe, delimiter, pipeline

I have a stream that is null delimited, with an unknown number of sections. For each delimited section I want to pipe it into another pipeline until the last section has been read, and then terminate.
In practice, each section is very large (~1GB), so I would like to do this without reading each section into memory.

For example, imagine I have the stream created by:

```
for I in {3..5}; do seq $I; echo -ne '\0'; 
done
```

I'll get a steam that looks like:

```
1
2
3
^@1
2
3
4
^@1
2
3
4
5
^@
```

When piped through `cat -v`.

I would like to pipe each section through `paste -sd+ | bc`, so I get a stream that looks like:

```
6
10
15
```

This is simply an example. In actuality the stream is much larger and the pipeline is more complicated, so solutions that don't rely on streams are not feasible.

I've tried something like:

```
set -eo pipefail
while head -zn1 | head -c-1 | ifne -n false | paste -sd+ | bc; do :; done
```

but I only get

```
6
10
```

If I leave off `bc` I get

```
1+2+3
1+2+3+4
1+2+3+4+5
```

which is basically correct. This leads me to believe that the issue is potentially related to buffering and the way each process is actually interacting with the pipes between them.

Is there some way to fix the way that these commands exchange streams so that I can get the desired output? Or, alternatively, is there a way to accomplish this with other means?

In principle this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233480/split-stdout-and-pipe-each-piece-to-command), and I could certainly write a program that reads stdin into a buffer, looks for the null character, and pipes the output to a spawned subprocess, as the accepted answer does for that question. Given the general support of streams and null delimiters in bash, I'm hoping to do something that's a little more "native". In particular, if I want to go this route, I'll have to escape the pipeline (`paste -sd+ | bc`) in a string instead of just letting the same shell interpret it. There's nothing too inherently bad about this, but it's a little ugly and will require a bunch of somewhat error prone escaping.

## Edit

As was pointed out in an answer, `head` makes no guarantees about how much it buffers. Unless it only buffers single byte at a time, which would be impractical, this will never work. Thus, it seems like the only solution would be to read it into memory, or [write a specific program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233480/split-stdout-and-pipe-each-piece-to-command).

Comment: Would `xargs -0 -n 1` be useful here?

Comment: Do you really need `bc`? If you're just using integers, why not stick with native shell math?

Comment: BTW, re: `set -e`, see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry. Its behavior is frequently *very* unintuitive (and [wildly incompatible between different shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/)), to the point that it arguably does more harm than good.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick As far as my reading of xargs manual goes, it will read the null delimited strings and pass them into the command invocation. This doesn't work for two reasons, a) it reads it into memory, and b) it will fail if it fills the maximum command length for the current shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `paste -sd+ | bc` is just to illustrate an example pipeline. It's not how would actually do this.

Comment: @Erik, ...are the *individual strings* (that is, the spans between the NULs) longer than ARG_MAX (when concatenated with the environment size)? `xargs -0 bash -c 'for arg; do paste -sd+ <<<"$arg" | bc; done' _` should work as long as no single NUL-delimited string is too large to fit. On modern Linux, that's well over 100kb, so unless you're polluting the environment with unnecessary `export`s I'd expect it to be fine for most reasonable use cases.

Comment: (aside, re: the use of `printf` rather than `echo -e` -- the POSIX spec for `echo` only permits a single argument value to behave as an option, and that's `-n`; moreover, `-n` -- while allowed -- makes output unspecified, so it's not portable to use either. Bash violates black-letter language of the standard when treating `-e` as anything other than a string to be printed, and some runtime and compile-time configurations will make its behavior compliant, such that `echo -e` won't work; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, each individual string is over 1G, so xargs is really out of the question. (aside: I really appreciate the asides about set and echo)

Comment: Gotcha. I'd almost be tempted in that case to find the NULs' byte offsets and then use `dd` to pull each one out in a separate command. OTOH, generating that list of offsets is a job for C/Go/Rust/another system-programming language; and once you've pulled in such a tool, might as well use it for the whole job.

Comment: ...one *can* use `read` with its `-n` argument to read smaller chunks, and then evaluate its exit status to know whether that chunk was terminated with a NUL, writing them incrementally to a pipeline... but the performance cost of `read`'s 1-byte granularity is going to make that expensive, even if it is functional in terms of not running out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, the only real solution seemed to be writing a program to do this specifically. I wrote one in rust called `xstream-util`. After installing it with `cargo install xstream-util`, you can pipe the input into

```
xstream -0 -- bash -c 'paste -sd+ | bc'
```

to get the desired output

```
6
10
15
```

It doesn't avoid having to run the program in bash, so it still needs escaping if the pipeline is complicated. Also, it currently only supports single byte delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your original code is that `head` doesn't guarantee that it won't read more than it outputs. Thus, it can consume more than one (NUL-delimited) chunk of input, even if it's emitting only one chunk of output.

`read`, by contrast, guarantees that it won't consume more than you ask it for.

```
set -o pipefail
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
  bc <<<"${line//$'\n'/+}"
done < <(build_a_stream)
```

---

If you want **native** logic, there's nothing more native than just writing the whole thing in shell.

Calling external tools -- including `bc`, `cut`, `paste`, or others -- involves a `fork()` penalty. If you're only processing small amounts of data per invocation, the efficiency of the tools is overwhelmed by the cost of starting them.

```
while read -r -d '' -a numbers; do  # read up to the next NUL into an array
  sum=0                             # initialize an accumulator
  for number in "${numbers[@]}"; do # iterate over that array
    (( sum += number ))             # ...using an arithmetic context for our math
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$sum"
done < <(build_a_stream)
```

---

For all of the above, I tested with the following `build_a_stream` implementation:

```
build_a_stream() {
  local i j IFS=$'\n'
  local -a numbers
  for ((i=3; i<=5; i++)); do
    numbers=( )
    for ((j=0; j<=i; j++)); do
      numbers+=( "$j" )
    done
    printf '%s\0' "${numbers[*]}"
  done
}
```